# Clear Linux desktop doesn't start in a virtual machine

Tags: system-installation, graphics, desktop-environment, clear-linux

I'm trying to run Clear Linux in a VM. I've tried the [vmdk image and installation image](https://download.clearlinux.org/image/) in both VMware Player and Virtualbox without success

In VMware Player it always hang up forever on startup after these lines

```
kvm: no hardware suport
rtc_cmos rtc_cmos: nvmem registration failed
intel_powerclamp: CPU does not support MWAIT
```

In Virtualbox it passes that step and I've [added the userspace](https://clearlinux.org/documentation/clear-linux/guides/maintenance/enable-user-space#enable-user-space) and run all console applications successfully.

But when I tried starting gdm it failed. After `systemctl start gdm` the TTY1 shows the prompt again and I can type commands into it, but the letters I type enter randomly into the TTY1 and TTY7 , and the CPU usage is high. If I change to other TTYs the same thing happen, some characters go into the current TTY and some into TTY7, but nothing is shown on TTY7. It's very hard to type but if I managed to finish the command then I got some messages like this

```
(gedit:15567): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:41:28:350: cannot open display:
```

If I run `startx` or `startxfce4` directly then I got the following error messages

```
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

My CPU is i5-7200U. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: the same @ parallels VM
https://github.com/clearlinux/distribution/issues/264